# Setting up a serial connection via bluetooth

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, serial, raspbian-stretch

I have a [GSM HAT](https://www.waveshare.com/gsm-gprs-gnss-hat.htm) module which I am trying to use as a remote sms receiver, which my RPI will connect to using bluetooth. The problem I am facing is **setting up a serial connection via bluetooth**.

Out of the box I couldn't connect to the GSM HAT via bluetooth, but after digging 
I had to install these packages: `bluealsa pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`, start pulseaudio: `sudo pulseaudio --start` and restart bluetooth `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth` to successfully make a connection:

```
[bluetooth]# connect 38:1C:4A:2B:F0:F8
Attempting to connect to 38:1C:4A:2B:F0:F8
[CHG] Device 38:1C:4A:2B:F0:F8 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 38:1C:4A:2B:F0:F8 ServicesResolved: yes
```

But looking through syslogs there are some worrying messages:

```
Aug 25 23:35:12 raspberrypi bluetoothd[475]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for 38:1C:4A:2B:F0:F8: Protocol not available
Aug 25 23:35:13 raspberrypi bluealsa[499]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: Unsupported AT message: CMD: command:+CLCC, value:(null)
Aug 25 23:35:13 raspberrypi bluealsa[499]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: Unsupported AT message: SET: command:+CLIP, value:1
Aug 25 23:35:13 raspberrypi bluealsa[499]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: Unsupported AT message: SET: command:+CCWA, value:1
```

To set up a **serial over bluetooth** connection I tried [this config](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/bluetooth/serial-over-bluetooth), but after a reboot it didn't work. It didn't even reconnect to a GSM HAT.

Then I tried setting it manually with `sudo rfcomm connect hci0 38:1C:4A:2B:F0:F8`, but I've got this:

```
humberd@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo rfcomm connect hci0 38:1C:4A:2B:F0:F8
Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused
```

I followed [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/6nchaj/guide_how_to_establish_bluetooth_serial/).
How to make it work?